# UEFI Enabled; unable to get IP address from DHCP, WDS

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, pxe-boot, dhcp-server, wds, mdt

I'm trying to boot PCs from a Windows 2012R2 WDS server in UEFI mode. it works fine BIOS mode, but I want to boot from UEFI mode.

I have change the boot setting to UEFI mode; secure boot in BIOS.

I am using Dell laptops and when I try to boot from NIC IPv4 under UEFI boot shows as below.

```
Checking Media Presence........... Media Present... Start PXE over IPv4.
```

========================================================================

then it hold for a while to get IP address from DHCP server then fails and prompts to reboot laptop.

Comment: What is the model of hte laptops and the BIOS version that you are using on the devices?

Comment: Dell latitude 5490  and Bios version is 1.7.0

Comment: Can you update them to the latest bios version? (1.8.3). Also, can you validate that your DHCP server is responding to all clients?

Comment: Yes sure. Will update on this.

Comment: Adding it to it, If I boot the laptop to OS, it will pick the IP address, but from PXE IP is not picking.

Comment: I have created a chat room to declutter the comments:
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93193/pxe-troubleshooting-temp
Can you join me there?

Answer (score 0):

When normal PXE with BIOS works, your should check if you have enabled WINS on your Network card (under TCPv4 Settings) of your WDS Server. When yes, disable it :)

[image]

Comment: could you verify this?

Comment: did not work thomas.